# Exporting an Excel file to .html -- issues

Tags: excel

Can anybody help me with this?

I am taking a table in Excel and exporting it as a web page.  I noticed that the webpage rendered things differently -- such as spacing (it's putting in LOTS of white space where there should be none).  Also, it's displaying columns that were hidden in my excel file. 
Can anybody let me know how to export this so that the space rendering is not so different?

Also, does anybody know how to export this in a way where I can keep some Excel functions (i.e. sort, filtering, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

For hidden columns, Excel's html format simply doesn't respect them.  I set my column width to 1 pixel to "hide" them.  If you have a lot of them together, it looks terrible in Excel and creates even more white space in the html, but I couldn't come up with a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [Appizy](http://appizy.com/en) to do it. It's a render service from .ods to .html :

1. First transform your Excel file into an OpenDocument with Open or LibreOffice
2. Convert it  using the html render tool of Appizy. The hidden cells will have the css attribute "display:none"

If you don't want your formulas to be working, the free version should be fine for you. I hope it can help.

BR, Nicolas